# Linux shell on multiple files

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

i have a file 1 which contain:

`aaaaaaa
bbbbbbb
ccccccc`

file 2:

`ddddddd
eeeeeee
fffffff`

file n:

`ggggggg
hhhhhhh
iiiiiii`

how to use regex shell linux to pre-add `thisistheresult` and have a result file like this :

`thisistheresultaaaaaaa,bbbbbbb,ccccccc
thisistheresultddddddd,eeeeeee,fffffff
thisistheresultggggggg,hhhhhhh,iiiiiii`

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `paste` and `sed`:

```
paste -s file* -d',' | sed 's/^/thisistheresult/'
```

Comment: i got this 
`
thisistheresultaaaaaaa <br/>
,bbbbbbb<br/>
,ccccccc<br/>
`
it is not right.

Comment: hmmm, the output I get is exactly what you want. I'm trying to understand the behaviour you see.

Comment: @YOU, what do you get with just `paste -s file* -d,`

Comment: how to downline in comment ?

Comment: @YOU The command is good. Make sure your files do not have windows `CR+LF`. Run it against `dos2unix` utility if you imported the files from windows.

Comment: Thanks it appear wrong in Lubuntu ,but right in windows 7 ,i dont know why ,can you re-add 'http://yoursite.com/a/b.gtn?action=ab&file&attach=' instead of "thisismyresult" ,i got trouble when change the string

Comment: @YOU, use this in the sed part: `sed 's#^#yoursite.com/a/b.gtn?action=ab\&file\&attach=#'`

Comment: You did me a great help .Hope you all the best .Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the file name begins with `file`.
The following code should work in bash.

```
for i in file*; do echo -n 'thisistheresult'; paste -sd, $i; done
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
> for f in file*
> do
> echo thisistheresult$(tr '\n' ',' < $f)
> done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find -name 'file*' | xargs -iF tcsh -c "tr '\n', ',' < F | sed 's/^/thisistheresult/' && echo" > result.file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
paste -s * | tr '\t' ',' | awk 'BEGIN { OFS = ""}{print "thisistheresult",$0}'
```

Output:

```
thisistheresultaaaaaaa,bbbbbbb,ccccccc
thisistheresultddddddd,eeeeeee,fffffff
```

if you want space between "thisistheresult" and "aaaaaaa" just get rid of BEGIN command:

```
paste -s * | tr '\t' ',' | awk '{print "thisistheresult",$0}'
```

output:

```
thisistheresult aaaaaaa,bbbbbbb,ccccccc
thisistheresult ddddddd,eeeeeee,fffffff
```